# How can I run a command five times using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I run a command five times in a row?

For example:

```
5 * send_sms_to("xxx");
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

To run a command 5 times in a row, you can do

```
5.times { send_sms_to("xxx") }
```

For more info, see the [`times` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#M000187) and there's also the [`times` section](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Looping_with_for_and_the_Ruby_Looping_Methods#The_Ruby_times_Method) of [Ruby Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Essentials)

Comment: In case you're wondering, the zero-based index is passed as the block arg

Answer (score 46):

You can use the [`times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) method of the class `Integer`:

```
5.times do 
   send_sms_to('xxx') 
end
```

or a `for` loop

```
for i in 1..5 do
  send_sms_to('xxx')
end
```

or even a `upto`/`downto`:

```
1.upto(5) { send_sms_to('xxx') }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using ranges:

```
(1..5).each { send_sms_to("xxx") }
```

Note: [ranges](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html) constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively.